# How to increase Input field value on clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

[cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3aDp.jpg)

when I click the pulse button, take the value at the input field and increase the value and show it in there but if I add more than one item (like the image shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3aDp.jpg ) then I click the pulse button second or another row the value increase on first-row input field NOT that relevant clicked row input field value (I'm adding that row using a .appent the reason when I click right side product it will add to the left side table) how can I solve it pls see blow I attached my code

```js
//increase product quantity
function pluse() {
  let qnty = +$('#qnty').val();
  let price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
  qnty = qnty + 1;
  let subtotal = price * qnty;
  $('#qnty').val(qnty);
  $('#subtotal').val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
}

//decrease product quantity
function minus() {
  let qnty = +$('#qnty').val();
  let price = +$('#price').val();
  if (qnty > 1) {
    let newQnty = qnty - 1;
    let NewSubtotal = newQnty * price;
    $('#qnty').val(newQnty);
    $('#subtotal').val(NewSubtotal.toFixed(2));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_name'];?>"></td>
  <td>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button type="button" class="input-group-text pluse" data-target="qnty" onclick="pluse(this)"><i class="fal fa-plus">+</i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-file" style="width:100px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control qnty " value="1" id="qnty" name="qnty[]">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button type="button" class="input-group-text minus" onclick="minus()"><i class="far fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext .price" name="price[]" id="price" value="1500.00"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" value="1500.00"></td>
  <td><a href="" class="btn text-danger">&cross;</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please dont add unrelated tags.

Comment: Please do another take on your explanation. I understand nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'm learning english, please forgive my mistakes...

You need to rewrite your functions to accept an objet by parameter like this:

```
function pluse(ObjectClicked)
```

also you need to send the object to the function like this:

```
 onclick="minus(this)"
```

you need learn about Jquery selections like "closest" , "find" etc

I rewrite your code, and I hope this code help you to understand:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome 4.7-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container" >
        <!--question HTML CODE-->
        <tr>
            
            <td>
                <div  class="input-group mb-3" >
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button  type="button" class="input-group-text pluse" data-target="qnty" onclick="pluse(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file" style="width:100px">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control qnty " value="5" id="qnty" name="qnty[]">
                    </div>
                    <div  class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button type="button" class="input-group-text minus" onclick="minus(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button  type="button" class="input-group-text pluse" data-target="qnty" onclick="pluse(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file" style="width:100px">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control qnty " value="6" id="qnty" name="qnty[]">
                    </div>
                    <div  class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button  type="button" class="input-group-text minus" onclick="minus(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group mb-3" >
                    <div  class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button  type="button" class="input-group-text pluse" data-target="qnty" onclick="pluse(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div   class="custom-file" style="width:100px">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control qnty " value="6" id="qnty" name="qnty[]">
                    </div>
                    <div   class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button  type="button" class="input-group-text minus" onclick="minus(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Add the div class="input-group mb-3" that you need -->
                          
            </td>
            
        </tr>



        <!---->
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Question Script-->
    <script>
        //increase product quantity
        function pluse(ObjectClicked){
            // create new value adding 1
            var newQuantity= parseInt( $(ObjectClicked).closest('.input-group').find("input").val() ) + 1;

            //set the value to the closest input
            $(ObjectClicked).closest('.input-group').find("input").val(newQuantity);

            //maybe you need to redefine the formulas for sub and total 
        }

        //decrease product quantity
        function minus(ObjectClicked){
            // verfify the actual value                  
            var Quantity= parseInt( $(ObjectClicked).closest('.input-group').find("input").val() );

            //verfique the quantity
            if (Quantity>0)
                {
                // create new value substractig 1
                var newQuantity= parseInt( $(ObjectClicked).closest('.input-group').find("input").val() ) - 1;

                 //set the value to the closest input
                $(ObjectClicked).closest('.input-group').find("input").val(newQuantity);

              }

            //maybe you need to redefine the formulas for sub and total 
        
            }
        
    </script>
    <!-- -->
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add new lines manually or using Jquery